# Синтаксические ошибки

Tags: синтаксис

Я остановился и выстрелил в воздух, чтобы предостеречь об опасности.
Правительство отмечает о необходимости помощи отечественному товаропроизводителю.
Хотелось бы поделиться о том, что беспокоит пенсионеров.
Скажите пожалуйста, где в данных предложениях синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: Если это домашнее задание, то попробуйте начать делать его самостоятельно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я остановился и выстрелил в воздух, чтобы предостеречь <s>об</s> **от** опасности.
Правительство отмечает <s>о необходимости</s> необходимость помощи отечественному товаропроизводителю.
Хотелось бы поделиться <s>о том</s> тем, что беспокоит пенсионеров.